# Overwrite Core Data field

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi I am fairly new to core data and have recently started doing some tutorials. I have successfully added new data via core data but am struggling to overwrite the data. I have a textfield where I want to be able to save the text written in that textfield to core data. This is how I have added new data. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thank you

P.S. I believe it has to do with the way I do "insertNewObjectForEntityForName"

```
-(IBAction)saveData
{

AppDelegate *appDelegate = 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = 
[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newContact;
newContact = [NSEntityDescription
              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Gameinfo"
              inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newContact setValue:[self valuefromtextfield] forKey:@"score"];
//[newContact setValue:@"mark" forKey:@"currentLevel"];
NSError *error;
[context save:&error];

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` you are creating a **NEW** entity. If you want to edit an **existing** entity you need to

```
AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Gameinfo"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *someArray = [app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Then `someArray` has all of the entities named `Gameinfo` in it. Find the one you want and edit whatever properties you want. Then call `save` on the managed object context.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't recognize the part where you said "self.app". Obviously I replaced the "app" with the appropriate name of my app but no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: Oh right, you need to import your "AppDelegate.h" and then do `AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`. This assumes that you're using the default core data setup (how XCode auto-sets it up). I'll edit my answer

Comment: ah okay thanks Dustin. Last question (really sorry if this is very obvious), how would I edit the properties? If you notice at the top I am trying to edit "score". So if I had score as 100 before (a string), how would I edit it via the array method you described? It just shows me the managed object when I nslog the array. Thanks!

Comment: [(Gameinfo *) [someArray objectAtIndex:0] setScore:@"value"]; sorry for bad formatting; im on my phone. This assumes you've imported Gameinfo.h

Comment: No worries, sorry for the hassle:) But I think I may be doing this whole core data thing wrong. my app name is "testgame" and I have a testgame.xcdatamodeld file where I have created inside of it the entity Gameinfo. Now you mention I need to import Gameinfo.h... is this what you are referring too? Thanks

Comment: Core data will generate files for you; it's in one of the menus. You're doing everything right from what I can see. Generating the classes just makes working with the data easier because you can treat managed objects the same as normal objects.

Comment: Bare with me here but it does not seem to work. It does not recognize Gameinfo.h or "setScore" so I tried [[someArray objectAtIndex:0] setValue:@"blah" forKey:@"score"]; With no luck. Any other suggestions? Thank you so much

Comment: Nvm the issue was it was at objectAtIndex:1. Thanks for your help!